# Cómo usar Paste0 para añadir letras al final del string?

Tags: r, string, substring

Tengo un df que contiene una columna con números de identificación

```
df1

ID=c("5435","1234","1234","998761","127634")
```

Todos los ID's tienen que tener una longitud de 6 dígitos, debiendo añadir ceros al final a aquellos que tienen menos de 6, de tal manera que obtenga al final:

```
ID=c("543500","123400","123400","998761","127634")
```

He pensando hacerlo usando:

`df$ID<-ifelse(nchar(dfID)<=6, paste0("00", df$ID), df$ID))`, pero el problema que me encuentro es que paste0 une los ceros al principio del string.

¿Existe alguna manera de hacer que una los ceros al final? No he encontrado cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 3):

Si inviertes el orden de los parámetros en `paste0` obtienes los ceros al final:

```
ID=c("5435","1234","1234","998761","127634")
ID<-(ifelse(nchar(ID)<6, paste0(ID, "00"), ID))
ID

>[1] "543500" "123400" "123400" "998761" "127634"
```

Pero en esta solución solo valdría para números que tengan 4 dígitos o 6.

---

Si usas la librería `stringi` puedes usar la función `stri_pad_right` y le pasas al segundo parámetro el numero de dígitos que ha de tener.

Así si tiene 1,2,...5 le añade los 0's correspondientes.

```
library(stringi)

ID=c("5","14","123","9987","12763", "123456")
ID = stri_pad_right(ID, 6, 0)
ID

> [1] "500000" "140000" "123000" "998700" "127630" "123456"
```

Comment: Perfecto! Súper útil el stri_pad_right. Muchísimas gracias @lois6b

Comment: De nada @Caro ^^ Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta si te ha servido. Un saludo!